# Scale image both vertically and horizontally within a gridlayout

Tags: java, android, layout, grid

I am new to Android development, and I am trying to use the GridLayout to create rows with 3 columns, each column with a imageview. In this case I am using a square image created in photoshop, all red, just for testing.

**This is the xml I currently use:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="me.andrewlarsen.testapp.MenuActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/redblock"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6" />

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The xml above gives a result looking like this:**

[image]

So as you can see I got 2 rows, that is different from eachother. On all 3 columns in the first row I've added **android:scaleType="fitXY"** however it only scales horizontally, not vertically.

I want it to scale up, in both directions so the result would be a square just larger.

**I am trying to make it look like this:**

[image]

When I am using android:scaleType="fitXY" I would expect the image to scale up both in X direction (horizontally) and Y direction (vertically) however it does not do so.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: This is because your children Views will inherit the parent's paddings. I.e.: The RelativeLayout's ones.

Comment: Thats true, but even if I remove the padding from the relativelayout the images doesn't scale up vertically, only horizontally. So I get the same result, but with less padding.

Comment: One rough trick would be to use the image as a **background**, instead of a **src**. Backround images are always scaled in both sizes. And you don't have to specify a `scaleType`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: Used the xml as I wrote in my question, and changed the 6 lines of src with background, and this is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/dbf6e065333c0d0695839767d7886b0c.png now both rows scale horizontally even the row where I do not use scaleType. However it does not scale vertically :/

Comment: Then I guess there's some margin/padding **in the image itself** (maybe, transparent).

Comment: The image itself is 100x100, here you can see a screenshot where I added a imageview outside the gridlayout (as you can see the image is square): https://i.gyazo.com/504f94be8952e4342901b00d8946f7d7.png

Comment: Maybe it's 80*80 plus a 10px transparent margin on all sides?

Comment: If that is the case should it still not scale up all sides equally so it still would be a square with the transparent margin on all sides (if there are any) ?

Comment: No, the cells are rectangular- Therefore it'll stretch to fit (and leave the 10 px margin wherever they are - if there are). OR, another option would be to use a color as a background, instead of an image (this will fill all the available cell space). But I guess the point here is to stretch the image.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can approach removing the transparent margins if there are any? Yes the point is to stretch the image, this is just a demo of what I am trying to accomplish I am not using this image in the final product.

Comment: Use Gimp (free) or Photoshop, if you have a license. Or any other graphical editor of your liking, to crop the image.

Comment: Tried with photoshop, same problem.

Comment: Can't tell more, without seeing the picture. I mean, not with naked eye. I should use a graphic editor.

Comment: Oh! How stupid from me. Try setting the ImageViews width and height to **match_parent**. So, they will fill the grid cell, instead of wrapping onto the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138368/discussion-between-andrew-larsen-and-rotwang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, had to use:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in each imageview element

Answer (score 0):

Try Remove weights (android:layout_columnWeight="1" and           android:layout_rowWeight="1" ), and what size your redblock ? if possible send your image.

Comment: Removed all columnWeight and rowWeight, and this is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/78f071157774cc9dc6ba68283e968a9f.png the picture I use is 100x100 with red background, created in paint. I know it would lose quality when scaling up, but it should still be possible to scale up in both directions?